# result of Nuxt build are break

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have tried build Nuxt with Nuxt generate and Nuxt build 
those are not build properly
it seem like break
when I use in dev, it was work perfectly 
but after I build it and run it, the 3rd party component and css not work at all,
is this because of my `nuxt.conf.js` wrong ??
I have asked this before but nothing solve yet,

here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/d0ddd22222fa871ae5.js',
        crossorigin: 'anonymous'
      }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700&display=swap'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quando&display=swap'
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin&display=swap'
      }
    ]
  },
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.css',
    '@/assets/css/input.css',
    '@/assets/css/animate.css'
  ],
  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/agile.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '@/plugins/model-gltf.js', mode: 'client'},
  ],

  router: {
    middleware: ['router'],
  },
  buildModules: [
  ],

  modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://myapi"
  },

  build: {
    vendor: ['vue-agile', 'vue-3d-model'],
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone here save my time please

Comment: its impossible to tell what wrong without full minimal reproduction

Comment: what does it mean

Comment: that mean a minimal repo where your problem reproduced is needed